# Build one-to-many association with ActiveRecord using alias for model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am building out a musician social site. Users can create bands, and they are considered from then on the `manager` of the band. I want to refer to a bands instance of a user as the `manager`.

Despite specifying the relationship in the models, and specifying `class_name: "User"` and `foreign_key: "manager"`, the app will not save a new Band to the database.

## user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :bands, foreign_key: 'manager'

    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_presence_of :password_digest
    validates_presence_of :username
    validates_uniqueness_of :username

    has_secure_password

    def admin?
        self.role == "admin"
    end
end
```

## band.rb

```
class Band < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'manager'
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_uniqueness_of :name
    validates_presence_of :description
end
```

## schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_12_27_040935) do

    create_table "bands", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.text "description"
        t.integer "manager_id"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
        t.index ["manager_id"], name: "index_bands_on_manager_id"
    end

    create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
        t.string "name"
        t.string "username"
        t.string "password_digest"
        t.datetime "created_at", null: false
        t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
        t.string "role", default: "user"
    end

end
```

## seeds.rb

#### Edited seeds.rb

```
User.destroy_all
Band.destroy_all

user = User.new(name: 'John')
user.save
user = User.find_by_name('John')

user_band = user.bands.new(name: 'Band #1', description: 'My first band')

if user_band.save
    puts "Done"
else
    puts "Incomplete"
end
```

I run `rails db:seed`, and expect to see `'Done'` in the console.
I get `'Incomplete'`.

Testing in the rails console, the band instance has the error of `"Manager must exist"`

Also, a single user instance exists, with and id of 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I changed my migration file, which apparently was causing the issue. The `schema.rb` looks identical, but the `seeds.rb` is now this…

## models

*user.rb*
`has_many :bands, foreign_key: 'manager_id'`

*band.rb*
`belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'manager_id'`

## seeds.rb

```
User.destroy_all
Band.destroy_all

user = User.new(name: 'John', username: "johnny", password: "nice")
user.save
user = User.find_by_name('John')

user_band = Band.new(name: 'Band #1', description: 'My first band', manager_id: user.id)

if user_band.save
    puts "Done"
else
    puts "Incomplete"
end
```

The errors were: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.managers: INSERT INTO "bands" ("name", "description", "manager_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

## Changed migration file for bands

### Previously

```
create_table :bands do |t|
    t.belongs_to :manager, foreign_key: true
    t.string :name
    t.text :description
    t.timestamps
end
```

### Changed To

```
create_table :bands do |t|
    t.belongs_to :manager
    t.string :name
    t.text :description
    t.timestamps
end
```

Removed option `, foreign_key: true`, Dropped DB, ran migrations, and now.

## It Works…

Answer (score 1):

Update associations as follows:

band.rb

```
belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'manager_id'
```

user.rb

```
has_many :bands, foreign_key: 'manager_id'
```

Before creating band, manager should be present in user table.

```
manager = User.find(1)
band = manager.bands.new(name: "Jams", description: "Hey, its our first band.") 
if band.save
   puts "Done"
else
   puts "Incomplete"
end
```

Comment: Have tried, will not work. Receive errors. `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.managers: INSERT INTO "bands" ("name", "description", "manager_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: manager = User.find(1)...this will return manager and then create brand as manager.bands.new(name: 'My band')

Comment: where are you saying that `user = User.find(1)` should go?

Comment: Replace this with new queries:  jms = Band.new(name: "Jams", description: "Hey, its our first band.", manager_id: 1)

Comment: `user = User.find(1)
jms = Band.new(name: "Jams", description: "Hey, its our first band.", manager_id: user.id)` returns "Incomplete", when `foreign_key: 'manager'` In the models. If `foreign_key: 'manager_id'`, the above error is spit out.

Comment: Manager is specified, and does exist for certain in the DB.

Comment: manager = User.new(name: 'John') manager = manager.brands.new(name: "Jams", description: "Hey, its our first band.") if manager.save puts "Done" else puts "Incomplete" end

Comment: Thanks for your patience, but these all give same results as above.

Comment: `user = User.new(name: 'John')`

`user.save`

`user = User.find_by_name('John')`

`user_band = user.bands.new(name: 'Band #1', description: 'My first band')`

`user_band.save`

this works for me after rake db:seed and entries get added in tables

Comment: So, I'm assuming it's my system is misconfigured or something? Same Error.

Comment: If your application is onboarding then reset database and run migrations again and seed also. Might be this will help.

Answer (score 0):

band.rb

```
belongs_to :manager, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'manager_id'
```

user.rb

```
has_many :bands, foreign_key: 'manager_id'
```

To test try this:

```
manager = User.create(...user_information)
jms = Band.new(name: "Jams", description: "Hey, its our first band.")
jms.manager = manager
jms.save
```

If it fails, what is the output of `jms.errors`?

Comment: Thanks Keith. Get an error as follows. `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.managers: INSERT INTO "bands" ("name", "description", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?))`